# Unable to load native C .so files on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native

I have deployed a web app on tomcat 7 on ubumtu VM. App uses a jar file which inturn makes JNI calls to some native C SOs. I have done the following:
1. create /shared/lib under tomcat home, and added the unjarred class files plus the C SOs.
2. updated catalina.properties to look for the above dir under shared.loader
3. Added the above dir to PATH
4. Added CATALINA_OPTS to "-Djava.library.path" option to point to the above dir

Restarted tomcat multiple times, still getting 'Could not load file XXXX.SO"

What am I missing? I have seen almost every documentation available on this matter

Comment: found a solution to this? same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/location/of/your/shared-objects` to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat.conf` and restart Tomcat. This works for me on CentOS.